# I have problem installing the sql server 2008 r2 on windows server 2008 r2. It gives me the following error

Tags: sql-server

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup

The following error has occurred:

Error reading from file: C:\en_sql_server_2008_r2_standard_x86_x64_ia64_dvd_521546\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\sqlsupport_msi\PFiles\SqlServr\100\Setup\fe72iemr\e4grzzmx\x64\1033\ynzwp_7q.rtf.   Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=10.50.1600.1&EvtType=0xDF039760%25401201%25401

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Comment: Did you `verify that the file exists and that you can access it`?

Comment: This is a great example of a Server Fault question. Please ask it at http://ServerFault.com (or wait for the eventual migration)

Answer (score 1):

Did you check and make sure that the file exists and you can access it because we can't do much.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related to missing files on the installation media.

I had the same problem with SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise downloaded from MSDN. I decided to download Standard and then Web edition to copy missing files but unfortunately both copies were also corrupted. Some files were available in Web edition but not all. I've tired to download package with Enterprise edition for few times with no success! After few hours of downloading and copying files between images installation started successfully but it failed at final step with error message about missing DLL files. After that I gave up.

Currently I'm trying to download next copy again.

Comment: I must say I'm disappointed with R2 so far as the Management Tools seem buggy as hell, behaving like R1 beta or something... :7

Comment: Fix your computer. I and I bet ton of other people - ndont ahve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

just a suggestion. Try to shorten the Path by renaming en_sql_server_2008_r2_standard_x86_x64_ia64_dvd_521546.

Maybe it's beyond the restriction for paths.

"Although NTFS allows each path component (directory or filename) to be 255 characters long and paths up to about 32767 characters long, the Windows kernel only supports paths up to 259 characters long if no UNC is used for addressing" wikipedia

Greets